# How obtrudeValue() method of CompletableFuture works?

Tags: java, multithreading

As per oracle docs obtrudeValue(T value) method "Forcibly sets or resets the value subsequently returned by method get() and related methods, whether or not already completed. This method is designed for use only in error recovery actions, and even in such situations may result in ongoing dependent completions using established versus overwritten outcomes."

Reference: 
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#obtrudeValue-T-

I googled a lot but not able to understand what issue can this obtrudeValue method can cause.
Can anyone help me in understanding following:

- Is it safe to use obtrudeValue method?
- If obtrudeValue is not safe to use then which method of CompletableFuture can be used to read asynch value?
- In which situation obtrudeValue method can cause issues?

Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ObtrudeValue** simply set/overwritte the result of the **CompletableFuture**(in any case doesnt matter if future was done or not).

You should not use this method for setting the result of the **CompletableFuture**.

In most of the cases you should use the method **complete** or method **completeExceptionally**.
These method are safe and guarantee that the result is set only if the future is not completed and the result can not be changed by subsequent calling of these methods, so when you call the get() method you get always the first result setted by these methods.

The async value from the CompletableFuture you always get by calling **get** method.

You should use ObtrudeValue only in very special cases, when you want to recover from some uncorrect state, than you can reset/overrite the previous value.

Example:

```
CompletableFuture<String> fut = new CompletableFuture<>();
fut.complete("test1");
System.out.println(fut.get()); // test1
fut.complete("test2");
System.out.println(fut.get()); // test1 , value not overwritten

fut.obtrudeValue("obtrudeValue");
System.out.println(fut.get()); // obtrudeValue , overwrite the value even of completed future
fut.obtrudeValue("newObtrudeValue");
System.out.println(fut.get()); // newObtrudeValue , subsequent call overwrite the value

fut.complete("test3");
System.out.println(fut.get()); // newObtrudeValue , value not overwritten by calling complete
```

Comment: I have a service which listens for async update from some other service. Here I am using CompletableFuture and setting it with the value received in update because I always want to return latest updated value on every request. Do you see any issue if I use obtrudeValue() method in such scenario?

Comment: It will work, but you should not use CompletableFuture for this. If you need to set value from async update and read the last value on different thread, you can use for example AtomicReference (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html) , in update you will call atomicReference.set(latestValue) and in reading thread you will call atomicReference.get() and you will get the latest value.

Comment: I am still not convinced why I should not use obtrudeValue if it will work. What issue it can cause?

Comment: It will not cause any issue and it will work. But the method has the contract(javadoc api) that it should be used in error recovery actions, which is not your case. If someone else will read your code then he will have to think about the code little longer to understand what you are doing(he will not expects that you use obtrudeValue for object passing from one thread to another).